# Join Table sql windowsForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I would like to insert a record  into table RDV .

**The query of creation RDV Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RDV] (
[idRdv]       INT           NOT NULL,
[objet]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[objectif]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[DateRdv]     DATETIME      NULL,
[commentaire] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[archive]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[idClient]    INT           NULL,
[idUser]      INT           NULL,
[idResultat]  INT           NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_RDV] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idRdv] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([idClient]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([idClient]),
FOREIGN KEY ([idUser]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([idUser]),
FOREIGN KEY ([idResultat]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Resultat] ([idResultat])
```

There is here my code :

```
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Insert into RDV (objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire,idClient)Select'" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox4.Text + "',idClient from RDV where Client.idClient=RDV.idClient and idClient='"+comboBox2.SelectedValue+"'", con);
        sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Le RDV a été ajouté avec succés !");
    }
```

The Error was: **The multi-part identifier " Client.idClient " can not be bound.**

My syntax query it's wrong ??? if yes , how should I correct it .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look into parameterized queries. Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Please, Have you any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well as the error says there is no reference to the Client table in your query, so it won't find the identifier Client.idClient. Either use a join or put Client in your From.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is Insert syntax.

Insert into RDV ("table columns")
Values ("values")

Example: (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway');
```